# Using v8cgi/mysql, can I connect to a non default port?

Tags: javascript, mysql, server-side, v8cgi

I installed googles' [v8cgi](http://code.google.com/p/v8cgi/) javascript engine in an IIS server environment, which works like it should.

Using the engines' [API_MySQL module](http://code.google.com/p/v8cgi/wiki/API_MySQL), I'd like to connect to the MySQL database on that server, but not on the default port (3306). The regular connection method is `[MySQL].connect(host,root,pass,database);`. I've tried `'localhost:port'` and `'localhost,port'` but both arent't working. Does anyone know a method to connect to a non default port using this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, after having seen the source code of the API_MySQL module: *nope*. The connect call is hardcoded to use the default port (`unsigned int port` is hardcoded to 0).